# Why do DependencyProperties need facade properties/getters/setters

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I use WPF for some time now. But I still wonder, why do I need those facade properties when defining DependencyProperties?

Here is what I mean is this. To define a DependencyProperty you have to write something like this:

```cs
public static DependencyProperty IsActiveProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsActive", typeof(bool), typeof(MyClass), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetaData(false));
```

But you also have do write:

```
public bool IsActive
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(IsActiveProperty);
    set => SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value);
}
```

If you don't define the "IsActive" property, the code won't run. It will compile, but if you use "IsActive" in XAML code the program crashes.

But: The Setter and Getter of IsActive are never called! - The system itself always calls `SetValue()` and `GetValue()` directly. I myself also don't use those properties (and if I need them in Code behind, I could also call `SetValue` and `GetValue` directly).

So, if they are never used, why can't I omit these properties? Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: You have to use a thing how it is intended to be used, for the gory details you can always check how WPF was written: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyProperty.cs,4a20845df0b86ddd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why you need facade:

With current XAML Parser, XAML types are mapped to CLR types.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail):

> ...XAML is **not** by itself one of the common languages that is directly consumed by the CLR runtime. ... **XAML types are mapped to CLR types** to instantiate a run time representation when the XAML for WPF is parsed...

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail):

> Per the XAML language specification level, XAML types could be mapped to **any other type system**, which does not have to be the CLR, but that would require the creation and use of a different **XAML parser**

This is why this piece of code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="key" IsActive="true"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

or this one

```
<local:View IsActive="true"/>
```

requires getter and setter for `IsActive`.

### Why your breakpoints never hit wrappers:

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-loading-and-dependency-properties):

> The current WPF implementation of its XAML processor is inherently dependency property aware.

`GetValue` and `SetValue` are directly called from XAML but the XAML Parser still needs a **definition of your property** to know its **name**, **type** and **accessors** (get/set).

This is for the sake of computational performance.

For example when accessing a dependency property **from XAML**, this piece of code:

```
get
{
    var val = (bool)GetValue(IsActiveProperty);
    DoCustomThing(val);
    return val;
}
set
{
    SetCustomThing(value);
    SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value);
}
```

or this:

```
public bool IsActive
{
    get { return false; }
    set { }
}
```

will be the **exact equivalent** of this code:

```
public bool IsActive
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(IsActiveProperty);
    set => SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value);
}
```

This is why it is explicitly mentioned in docs that you shouldn't write anything in getter and setter of a dependency property. (It is a bad practice to have different code to run from XAML than code-behind. In other words: *don't touch the getter/setter*)

Use `PropertyChangedCallback` or `CoerceValueCallback` instead.

### Why you need `DependencyProperty`:

XAML property system [is more efficient for WPF than plain CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-loading-and-dependency-properties). Also, some WPF functionalities such as animation requires `DependencyProperty`.

> For implementation reasons, it is computationally **less expensive** to identify a property as a **dependency property** and access the property system **SetValue** method to set it, rather than using the property wrapper and its setter

`DependencyProperty` is `XAML`-only stuff. XAML can resolve binding path by its name as defined in `DependencyProperty.Register`. When `Binding` a `DependencyObject` tree to a `DataContext` XAML doesn't look for getter and setter because it already knows everything about it from the **registered** information.

*Note that the `DependencyProperty` object does **not** have to be `public` because `DependencyProperty.Register` adds it to the `ResourceDictionary` of its parent `DependencyObject` and binding system will find it there.*

For example this piece of xaml code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsActive}"/>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsActive}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

works without Getter and Setter

```
public class ViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty IsActiveProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsActive",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(ViewModel),
        new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

Although you can assign a *public property* to `Binding.Path`, [it does not necessarily require a public property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.path?view=netframework-4.8). It can work with public indexers, public collections, attached properties and dependency properties.

[image]
[image]

for more on this you can read [XAML property system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/properties-wpf)

---

### Conclusion:

If you remove getter and setter:

1. You will have a hard time accessing the `DependencyProperty` from C# (sometimes you may intentionally remove an accessor or the whole wrapper)
2. Your code won't compile if you use that `DependencyProperty` anywhere in XAML (except for `BindingPath`)

If you remove `DependencyProperty` and have a CLR property, you will miss all the benefits of WPF property system. Although you can easily setup your bindings but they will be less efficient performance-wise.

If you modify the code inside getter and setter, you will hurt simplicity and readability of your code.

Comment: @Bizhan is arguing that a program will compile regardless of a Binding.Path's value which is true but that does not answer the question

Comment: @Clemens I think the confusion of OP (why there is a need to define two things instead of one) indicates that someone must mention the WPF property system and compare it with CLR wrappers

Comment: Be aware than when `IsChecked="{Binding IsActive}"` (where `Mode=TwoWay` was redundant) works without a CLR wrapper for IsActive, this is just another implementation detail that you should not rely on. While the current WPF version may chose to directly call GetValue on the binding source, you can't be sure that the next version will do the same. In general, anything denoted by a Binding Path must be a public property, i.e. must have a getter. Hence a dependency property declaration without the CLR property wrapper is incomplete and should be avoided.

Comment: @Clemens yes `Mode=TwoWay` is redundant (not the point though). I disagree with what you said `anything denoted by a Binding Path must be a public property`. if it's a property it *must* be public, but generally at the best it's a *should* not a *must*. Also it's not a fair reason to avoid a feature just because it might not be there in future (which from my understanding is in the core of property system design and may not be change in the lifetime of WPF).

Comment: A non-empty Binding Path (or one that is not `.` in XAML) denotes a source property, or a set of nested properties, including indexers. That's why the type of `Binding.Path` is `PropertyPath`.

Comment: @Clemens `Path` requires a value not a property and that includes DP and AP

Comment: So thanks again for the answer, even if it is a little long (and therefor harder to understand). But if I'm understand this correctly, the XAML parser need the property accessors for performance reasons even if WPF never uses it.

Comment: you are welcome @MartiniBianco , this is a complicated topic and I suggest you read the MSDN carefully. I only tried to summarize those information. but the answer to your question is in the first line `XAML types are mapped to CLR types`. accessors are NOT faster than DP system since DPs are WPF resources. so in short, no, XAML parser needs the accessors because it can't function without it, if GetValue/SetValue are provided for bindings they will provide performance boost.

Comment: just to be more precise, by `if GetValue/SetValue are provided for bindings` I meant, if you chose to write DP instead of CLR types as a binding source. And by `they will provide performance boost` I meant to the WPF graphical pipeline (such as visuals and animations), the whole application may slow down if you overuse DPs, they create huge overheads.

Answer (score 3):

WPF calls GetValue and SetValue instead of calling our property accessors. because WPF doesn't use our property accessors, our breakpoints are never reached.

the property accessors are necessary. if we do not provide them, then we cannot reference them in XAML; conversely, if we do provide them, then we can reference them in XAML.

if we reference the property accessors in XAML, but they do not exist, then our program will absolutely not compile.

[image: error with int]

[image: error with binding]

Comment: @Bizhan i have updated my post with a screenshot of the error demonstrating that the getter and setter are indeed required. do you have an example demonstrating the behavior you describe?

Comment: I retracted my vote because I didn't know about this scenario, but in binding I'm 100% sure you don't need accessors.

Comment: You misunderstood my meaning

Comment: @Bizhan replacing the value of SomeProperty with a Binding does not change the fact that the program will not compile if the property that is referenced in XAML does not exist. i have edited my post with another screenshot demonstrating this

Comment: You misunderstood my meaning, pls see my answer

Comment: @KirkHorton Can you explain this a little more. You are saying, that it don't compile if I don't provide the Getter/Setter, but I already knew that. But I still don't understand why. - What I read between the lines is, that the DependencyProperty is part of WPF, but the Getter/Setter is needed by XAML. And because WPF only uses XAML, but XAML is also used elsewhere (like UWP or Xamarin), I have to provide both. Is that it?

Answer (score -1):

WPF needed some way to indicate whether a property is meant to be read-write, read-only, or write-only. There are several ways they could have done this. They could, for example, have made it something you specify when you register the DependencyProperty.

I think the reason they went with "make you write get/set methods" is because they get two benefits for the price of one: the methods tell the XAML compiler whether the property is writable or not; and they're also a mechanism that runtime code can use to read and write the property. If you leave off the getter or the setter, you're communicating your intention to both audiences. So you end up writing one set of code that serves both purposes, and ensures that they both stay in sync if you change your mind later.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. You can write to any writable dependency property by calling SetValue, regardless if there is a traditional property exposing it or not. If you want a readonly dependency property, then you call RegisterReadOnly instead of Register. The wrapper property is only for caller convenience and for XAML to use at compile time. It does not control the read/write abilities of the property. I would go as far as to say that if you make a writable dependency property and wrap it with a readonly CLR wrapper, you are sending a mixed message about how to use the property.